# Как передать массив классов, или класс из JavaScript в контроллер asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть класс в js:

```
class Question {
    x = getNumb();
    y = getNumb();
    s = getSymb();
    question = getQuest(this.x, this.y, this.s);
    rightAns = calculate(this.x, this.y, this.s);
}
```

Далее идет объявление массива с экземлярами класса, и вызов функции:

```
const questions = [
new Question(),
new Question(),
];

getInfo(score, questions.length, questions);
```

Функция, передающая значения в контроллер:

```
function getInfo(score, count, quest) {
    $.post("/Home/GetInfo", { score: score, count: count, quest: quest})
}
```

Сам контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetInfo(long score, long count, object[] quest)
{ }
```

С переменными **score** и **count** все работает - переменные передаются, т.к это int, а при попытке получить массив объектов ничего не передается. Как получить класс из js?

Понимаю, что можно сделать input type=hidden, но это дополнительные костыли. Хотелось бы без этого. Слышал что то про серриализацию, может она поможет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось. И как предполагалось, нужно просто напросто использовать сериализирование в JSON в javascript-файле, а уже в контроллере десериализировать обратно в объект(класс)